# Model implementation to segmentation task in Tensorflow 2.2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to run a CNN to segment medical images, and I'm following an article[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sLG6.png) that is kinda what I need.

I'm trying to implement it on Tensorflow 2.2.0 stack, but I'm having some issues, because the arcticle is not clear in how the layers are disposed and how the image "gets its original resolution" back.

- The last layer (conv6) output in my implementation is (22x22,1), but paper's output is (44x44,1) and I cant't figure out how to fix it;
- Alse, the paper uses PReLU as activation function, and I don't know how to use it on tensorflow. If I just type prelu, it throws error saying that dont recognizes prelu as activaction function. I'm aware that `keras.layers.PReLU` exists, but I don't know how to use in CNN that way;
- My current implementation throws the following error when I try to fit it:

```py
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 353 and 22 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](IteratorGetNext:1, binary_crossentropy/Log)' with input shapes: [1,353,353,1], [1,22,22,1].
```

I'm running on Ubuntu LTS 20.04, with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 Super GPU and Ryzen 7 2700X CPU with 16GB ram. I'm running the trainings on GPU.

X_train, Y_train are respectively the images and masks resized to 353x353, grayscale (same as the arcticle). Here follows how do I call the fit method:

```
IMG_WIDTH = 353
IMG_HEIGHT = 353
```

[...]

```
# LOADING MODEL
model = cnn_arcticle( IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT )

#SETTING UP FIT
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=tf.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2) )
model.summary()

earlystopper = EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1)
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('modelos_salvos/model_artigo_orig.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
# PERFORMING TRAINING
results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True, batch_size=1, epochs=10, callbacks=[earlystopper, checkpointer] )
```

Here follows my implementation:

```py
def cnn_arcticle( img_width, img_height, img_channels=1 ):
    
    inputs = Input( ( img_width, img_height, img_channels ), name="cnn_artigo" )
    c1a = Conv2D( 96, (13,13), padding='same', strides=(2,2), activation='relu' , name='conv1' ) (inputs)
    nr1 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization( c1a )
    mp1 = MaxPooling2D( (3,3), padding='same', strides=(2,2), name='max-pooling1' ) (nr1)
    
    c2a = Conv2D( 256, (5,5), padding='same', strides=(2,2), activation='relu', name='conv2a' ) (mp1)
    nr2 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization( c2a )
    c2b = Conv2D( 256, (5,5), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv2b' ) (nr2)
    mp2 = MaxPooling2D( (3,3), padding='valid', strides=(2,2), name='max-pooling2' ) (c2b)

    c3a = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv3' ) (mp2)
    c4a = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv4' ) (c3a)
    
    c5a = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv5a' ) (c4a)
    c5b = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv5b' ) (c5a)
    c5c = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv5c' ) (c5b)
    c5d = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv5d' ) (c5c)
    c5e = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv5e' ) (c5d)
    c5f = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv5f' ) (c5e)
    c5g = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv5g' ) (c5f)
    c5h = Conv2D( 384, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv5h' ) (c5g)
    c5i = Conv2D( 256, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv5i' ) (c5h)
    c6a = Conv2D( 1, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv6' ) (c5i)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c6a)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])

    return model
```

The summary output:

```sh
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cnn_artigo (InputLayer)      [(None, 353, 353, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 177, 177, 96)      16320     
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_LRN (TensorFlowO [(None, 177, 177, 96)]    0         
_________________________________________________________________
max-pooling1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 89, 89, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2a (Conv2D)              (None, 45, 45, 256)       614656    
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_LRN_1 (TensorFlo [(None, 45, 45, 256)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2b (Conv2D)              (None, 45, 45, 256)       1638656   
_________________________________________________________________
max-pooling2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 22, 22, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3 (Conv2D)               (None, 22, 22, 384)       885120    
_________________________________________________________________
conv4 (Conv2D)               (None, 22, 22, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5a (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5b (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5c (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5d (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5e (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5f (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5g (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5h (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5i (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 256)       884992    
_________________________________________________________________
conv6 (Conv2D)               (None, 22, 22, 1)         2305      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 22, 22, 1)         2         
=================================================================
Total params: 15,989,443
Trainable params: 15,989,443
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here follows two image prints with the arcticle's description of the mode. First, the [Table with the model's layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sLG6.png) and an [textual description of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJY7R.png)

Anyone can read the arcticle, and [here's the link to it](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11548-017-1649-7). The description is in section 2.3 (Materials and Methods > Architecture of the deep CNN)

Comment: Please provide the shape of your X_train and y_train and also the code that shows how you compile and  fit the model. By looking at your network architecture it looks like you are perfuming a classification as you are using Sofmax activation in last layers. However, your network output is (22,22,1) which does not make sense for a Softmax layer. I can help more if you proved more information.

Comment: @NimaAghli, actualy I've changed the softmax actiavtion layer to sigmoid as well. The error now is ```ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((1, 22, 22, 1) vs (1, 353, 353, 1))```. I don't now how to put the output in the same shape as the input :/

Comment: @NimaAghli actualy as I've understood some error, I've changed the question a little bit to make more clear what I don't know how to make. I ask you apologies to not make my question clear from the begining.